# Is this useRef unnecessary?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I'm trying to understand every line of this beautiful example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/r5qmj8m6lq

Could you please suggest the possible reason to utilise useRef on line 18:

```
const order = useRef(items.map((_, index) => index))
```

if it could be replaced by

```
var order = items.map( (_, index) => index )
```

(and then of course we have to refer to `order` rather than to `order.current`)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You actually asking about the difference between scoped variable and useRef, `var order` will be reinitialized on every render, hence if you make a change to `order`, it will reset on the next render, see the duplicate.

Comment: Also, you can read about the [`render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) function, in function component, the function's body is the render function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the reason for useRef here is to have a container which manages mutable values without causing a rerender cycle on value change